# Angular Reactive Forms: Use .controls property with formGroupName

Tags: javascript, angular, formbuilder, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I'm curious if it's possible to use the `myForm.controls` property in an Angular Reactive form instead of defining an AbstractControl for every instance?

This method is suggested in NG-Book but it's not used with nested forms and FormGroupName.

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
<div>
  <input type="text"
         id="nameInput"
         placeholder="Product"
         [formControl]="myForm.controls['name']">
   <div *ngIf="myForm.controls['name'].hasError('required')">Name is 
   required</div>
</div>
<div formGroupName="address">
  <input type="text"
         id="streetInput"
         placeholder="Enter Street"
         [formControl]="myForm.controls['street']">
   <div *ngIf="myForm.controls['street'].hasError('required')">Street is required</div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
export class App {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      'name':  ['', Validators.required],
      'address': fb.group({
        'street': ['', Validators.required],
      });
    } 
  }
}
```

I realize I can set `formControlName="street"` on the input but then I think I would have to use AbstractControl to determine it's validation state. Where as in my non-nested formGroup, I can just use `myForm.controls['name'].hasError('required')`.

Comment: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/26ghRmJAmlIWXMqcZ9jT?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, i understand your question well.

Do you want to get validation about nested from control?

Then, you can get `myForm.get('address').control['street'].hasError('required')` or `myForm.get('address').get('street').hasError('required')`

And you can change `hasError('required')` to `errors.required`.

These link is description about form validation.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#example-4

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation

If I misunderstand your question, comment.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed. I got it working with `myForm.get('address').control['street'].hasError('required')`. Thank you!

I also had to change `[formControl]="myForm.controls['street']"` to `formControlName="street"` on the input. This part is still a bit confusing to me though. If it were NOT nested it requires to be `[formControl]="addGymForm.controls['name']"` on the input. Why is the syntax so much more simple for nested formGroups?

Comment: Edit:
If it were NOT nested it requires to be `[formControl]="myForm.controls['street']"` on the input. Why is the syntax so much more simple for nested formGroups?

Comment: I don't understand your question. your question mean "Is syntex of `nested formgroup` more simple than `not nested formgroup`?"